# Difference between writeObject and writeUTFBytes

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets

I'm working on the project in AIR (AS3). I have a Socket Server running on my computer, and two ipads connected over wifi, which should communicate with the server.
I wrote a basic "send" function which works this way :

```
function send(_type:String, _data:String):void
{
    socket.writeObject({ type: _type, data: _data});
    socket.flush();
}
```

When the server reads a response, it just sends it to the other socket (ipad) to achieve indirect ipad-to-ipad communication.
The port is above 1024.

Sometimes, especially when both ipads send a message at approximately the same time, nothing is sent back from the server. I colleague working on a different project but with AIR AS3 sockets use WriteUTFBytes/readUTFBytes instead of my writeObject/readObject and he doesn't seem to have this problem.

My question is basically, is there a fundamental difference between these two functions ?
How can I prevent this bug ? I'm suspecting that somehow the server doesn't like to send a message on a socket currently carrying another message. Am I right ?

**Update:**
Server side message handling :

I have a listener for the ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA event, which looks like this :

```
private function onData(e: ProgressEvent):void
{
    var currentSocket:Socket = e.currentTarget as Socket;
    var p:Object = currentSocket.readObject();
    switch(p.type)
    {
    // Process data based on the type of event
    }
}
```

**Update 2** : I've done some debugging with Wireshark, and I've  noticed that sometimes, my flash trace says it sent the message, and it doesn't appear in Wireshark (which shows PDU fragment, so I guess even merged packages should show up).

Second thing (**third update**), is when both ipads send a message at the same time, they are properly shown in Wireshark but the server only reads the first one ! Although both ACK are presents. I don't understand.

Comment: You might want to add the server side code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will solve your problem but when you do network stuff you must always prepare a protocol because you have no guarantee that you'll receive all data in one time.

In your case, you should send the lenght of your data before send the data themselves and in sever-side waits for enought data before deserialize.

You should consider to do something like this and call read function for each DataEvent :

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.net.Socket;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    public class TestSocket extends Sprite
    {
        public var sendSocket : Socket;
        public var writeBuffer : ByteArray = new ByteArray;
        public var readBuffer : ByteArray = new ByteArray;
        private var readLenght : int = -1;

        public function send(_type:String, _data:String):void
        {
            // Write your object to a buffer to be able to read its lenght
            writeBuffer.clear();
            writeBuffer.writeObject({ type: _type, data: _data});

            // Send the length to the server
            sendSocket.writeInt(writeBuffer.length);

            // Send your object
            writeBuffer.position = 0;
            sendSocket.writeBytes(writeBuffer);

            sendSocket.flush();
        }

        public function read(socket : Socket) : Object
        {
            // Read all avaibles Bytes
            socket.readBytes(readBuffer);

            // Check if we have enough data to read lenght
            if(readLenght == -1 && readBuffer.length > 8)
                readLenght = readBuffer.readInt();

            // Check if we can read object
            if(readLenght != -1 && readBuffer.length >= readLenght + 8)
            {
                // Reset data length
                readLenght = -1;

                // Read object
                var o : Object = readBuffer.readObject();

                // Remove read data
                var tmp : ByteArray = new ByteArray;
                tmp.writeBytes(readBuffer);
                readBuffer.clear();
                readBuffer.readBytes(tmp);

                return o;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this really usefull on a local network ? I thought your solution was for Internet use, where you cannot guarantee the data transmission.

Comment: I'm not sure but may be your problem is due to this.